# Windows 8.1 automatic repair loop (INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE)

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, crash

Today, my pc with Windows 8.1 installed suddenly started crashing on start up, and then rebooting and showing the 'Automatic repair' screen. I tried solving this in multiple ways already:

- I tried creating a USB drive with a copy of Windows 8.1 on it on my laptop, and then on my pc select refresh pc - when I insert the USB drive it says the inserted media isn't valid. I don't have the original installation cd
- I tried using startup repair, it just runs for a minute and then it
  says the problem can't be fixed using startup repair
- I tried a system restore, but it gives the error '0x80070057'. Unfortunately, there's only one system restore available
- I tried using the following commands in the command prompt:

  ```
  bootrec /fixMBR     
  bootrec /Fixboot     
  bootrec /rebuildBCD
  ```

  However, after the last line it says that no installations were found
  (I made sure to activate the windows partition using `DISKPART`)

I didn't recently install any suspicious programs, and I've been running Windows 8.1 for over a year now without any problems. Can anyone please help me? I really need to be able to use my pc

**Update:**
I gives the error `INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE`. I've disconnected all my hard drives except the SSD that Windows is installed on, I made sure it is booted from, I changed the SATA cable, but nothing helped. Also, when I try to enter safe mode from the Automatic Repair screen, the `INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE` error message still shows

Comment: What method did you use to create the USB Drive, do you have access to another system at all?

Comment: @Sam3000 I have access to a laptop with Windows 10 installed

Comment: Have you used the media creation tool located here to create the USB drive you mentioned? It should create a valid installation media: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media

Comment: @Sam3000 yes I have, I tried both the regular and the regular N version (both 64-bits) as I wasn't sure which one I had, but neither worked

Comment: Do you see any error messages when it crashes on boot?

Comment: @Sam3000 it says 'Your pc ran into a problem and needs to restart' for about a second after the windows loading screen, then it restarts and goes to the automatic repair screen

Comment: @Sam3000 see my updated question, I missed part of the error message because it goes away so quickly

Comment: Have you tried typing: `bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy legacy` in the command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

*This appears to be a known problem with Windows 8.1 - dubbed the "Automatic Repair Loop" by many. Given that you have managed to make a recovery USB drive, the following has worked for some people:*

---

Step 1: Boot from your USB drive.

Step 2: Select "Advanced repair options"

Step 3: Select "Troubleshoot"

Step 4: Select "Advanced Options"

Step 5: Select "Start up settings"

Step 6: Select "Restart"

Step 7: The computer should restart. Now you want to hit the 4 key, which is safe mode.

Step 8: You should be able to log in now. Restart the computer and the computer should boot normally.

---

There are some alternatives to try if the above doesn't work:

Step 1: Boot from your USB drive.

Step 2: When the install screen pops up, look to the bottom left and select "Repair Your Computer".

Step 3: You will now see a screen that says "Choose an option". Select "Troubleshoot", then "Advanced Options", and finally "Command Prompt".

Step 4: You should now see the command prompt. Type "bcdedit" (without quotes) and hit enter.

Step 5: A list should have appeared. Towards the top, you should see "resumeobject" (It is under "default"). Highlight the long number, including the brackets, and copy.

Step 6: Now type "bcdedit /set (the long number you copied) recoveryenabled No" (Without quotes). Hit enter.

Step 7: You should now see the message "The operation completed successfully"

Step 8: Type "Exit" (Without quotes)

Step 9: Reboot

---

If this does not work, I would suggest returning to Command Prompt and following these steps, to check there isn't an issue with your SSD.

Step 1: Type "chkdsk /r C:" (Without quotes) The scan should start.

Step 2: This could take several hours depending on the size of your SSD

Step 3: Once the scan is done, type "exit" (without quotes).

Step 4: Reboot

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to get outta this automatic loop is to get into advanced options and choose command prompt. Then type this exactly all on one line .

```
copy c:\windows\system32\config\RegBack\*   c:\windows\system32\config
```

This will throw you back into your login screen with a temp profile.  Get yourself into user accounts and make a new account. Make sure you give it admin privileges . Reboot. At windows user screen login with new account. Delete previous user account.  Reboot and presto problem all gone.